# QGIS update point location from NMEA

Tags: qgis, elevation, altitude, nmea

Can a point in a layer have its X, Y, and Z coordinates defined by a live NMEA string?

What I'd like to have is a point that is constantly moving during an edit session based on the incoming GNSS receiver information.

That way, I could have the point do useful calculations based on expressions.  Like a cut or fill based on an attribute field.